# Regex-Problem in R: Select last appearance of pattern

Tags: r, regex

I'm having some problems with a regex-pattern in R:

given the following

```r
variable <- "bla bla bla bla bla Content bla bla bla Content bla bla bla bla"
```

I would like to drop everything that comes after the last appreance of "Content" (including "Content"). In the above example `Content bla bla bla bla` needs to be dropped, so that only `bla bla bla bla bla Content bla bla bla` stays.

```r
sub(".*Content.*^", "", variable )  # doesn't work
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Capture the first part and replace the full string with it: `sub('(.*Content).*', '\\1', variable)`.

Comment: This answer will exclude `Content` from the dropped string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(variable, "\\sContent(?!.*Content).*$")
[1] "bla bla bla bla bla Content bla bla bla"
```

Here we use negative look-ahead `(?!.*Content)` to assert that after some appearance of `Content` there is nor other appearance of the same string until the end of the string `$`.

You can use the same pattern with `sub` but have to include the argument `perl = TRUE` to activate the look-around functionality:

```
sub("\\sContent(?!.*Content).*$", "", variable, perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
sub('(.*)Content.*', '\\1', variable)
```

- output

```
[1] "bla bla bla bla bla Content bla bla bla "
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as efficient as @Chris Ruehlemann's answer, but I already typed it, so here it is. Count how many times the target work occurs and extract everything up to the "n" occurrence of targer.

```r
library(stringr)

variable1 <- "bla bla bla bla bla Content bla bla bla Content bla bla bla bla"
variable2 <- "bla bla  Content bla bla  Content bla bla  Content bla bla"

drop_after_last <- function(variable, target){
  num <- str_count(variable, target)
  str_extract(variable, paste0("^(.*",  target, "){", num, "}") )
}

drop_after_last(variable1, "Content")
#> [1] "bla bla bla bla bla Content bla bla bla Content"
drop_after_last(variable2, "Content")
#> [1] "bla bla  Content bla bla  Content bla bla  Content"
```